# Replacing text in line, with different strings using shell script

Tags: text, replace, inline, alternate

Was hoping someone can assist;

I've got an xml file where I want to search for a specific string and then replace with different text each time a match is found. For example I need to search for everything with machine tags within xml the file so the results look similar to;

```
...
<machine>devbox1.mydomain.com</machine>
...
<machine>devbox2.mydomain.com</machine>
...
<machine>devbox1.mydomain.com</machine>
...
<machine>devbox2.mydomain.com</machine>
...
<machine>devbox1.mydomain.com</machine>
...
...
```

I now have 4 new systems where I need to replace each occurrence of devbox* to end up something like;

```
...
<machine>newbox1.mydomain.com</machine>
...
<machine>newbox2.mydomain.com</machine>
...
<machine>newbox3.mydomain.com</machine>
...
<machine>newbox4.mydomain.com</machine>
...
<machine>newbox1.mydomain.com</machine>
...
...
```

I've made an initial attempt in the form of a bash script, by building a while loop to read each line and grep for the required string, but I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it?

Any tips or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks
C

Comment: You can also deserialize your xml to an object and use linq query to search and replace certain text in the object.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with xml and or how to code/manipulate it, so I had hoped to do the necessary changes via a shell script...

Comment: What do you want to do with xml?

Comment: I have an xml file that has multiple occurrences of system names (devbox1 and devbox2). I need to replace the multiple entries, to reflect the new system names (newbox1, newbox2, newbox3 and newbox4). Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there cannot be more than one `<machine>` tag per line (or at least not more than one of those to be replaced), this Python script should do the work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
from itertools import cycle

regex = re.compile('^(.*<machine>)devbox\d+(\.mydomain\.com</machine>.*)$')
box = cycle([1, 2, 3, 4])
for l in sys.stdin:
  m = regex.match(l)
  if m:
    l = m.group(1) + 'newbox' + str(next(box)) + m.group(2)
  print(l)
```

Save it to a file (say `newboxer.py`) and make executable, and then you can use:

```
> ./newboxer.py < input.xml > output.xml
```

Comment: @user2269537 The results would end up like... what?

Comment: The result would end up, with the new entries being newbox1 and newbox2 only (and not newbox3 and newbox4).

For example;

The 1st match on grep for machine has devbox1 - I need this replaced with newbox1.

The 2nd match on grep for machine has devbox2 - I need this replaced with newbox2.


The 3rd match on grep for machine has devbox1 - I need this replaced with newbox3.


The 4th match on grep for machine has devbox2 - I need this replaced with newbox4.


The 5th match on grep for machine has devbox1 - I need this replaced with newbox1.

and so on and so on

Comment: @user2269537 I understand. I have changed the solution to a Python script.